# two submit buttons out of three not working on html page

Tags: php, html, button, web-development-server

I have the following three blocks on a html page:

```
<!-- Login Modal -->
<div id="login" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
        <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
        <i onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
        <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Accedi</h2>
         <label for="email"></label>
      <p><input name= "email" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email" required></p>
      <label for="password"></label>
      <p><input name="password" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="password" placeholder="Inserisci la password" id="password" required></p>
      <p><input  class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Accedi" type="submit"></p>
        <p class="w3-large">Hai dimenticato la password? <a href="#" title="Reimposta la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('login','pwdreset')">Recupera la password</a></p>
         <p class="w3-large">Non sei registrato? <a href="#" title="Registrati" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('login','register')">Registrati</a></p>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Password reset Modal -->
<div id="pwdreset" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
    <form action="forgottenpsw.php" method="post"></form>
      <i onclick="document.getElementById('pwdreset').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
      
      <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Reimposta la Password</h2>
      <label for="email2"></label>
      <p><input name= "email2" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email2" required></p>
      
      <p><input class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Reimposta" type="submit"></p>
     
      <p class="w3-large"> <a href="#" title="Accedi" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('pwdreset','login')">Accedi a Clear IDD</a></p>
      <p class="w3-large">Non sei registrato? <a href="#" title="Registrati" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('pwdreset','register')">Registrati</a></p>
   </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Register Modal -->
<div id="register" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
    <form action="register.php" method="post"></form>
      <i onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
      <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Registrati</h2>
      <label for="fname"></label>
      <p><input name= "fname" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" id="fname" required></p>
      <label for="surname"></label>
      <p><input name= "surname" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" id="surname" required></p>
      
      <label for="email3"></label>
      <p><input name= "email3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email3" required></p>
      <label for="password3"></label>
      <p><input name="password3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="password" placeholder="Inserisci la password" id="password3" required></p>
      <label for="password4"></label>
      <p><input name= "password4" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Conferma la password" id="password4" required></p>
      <p><input  class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Registrati" type="submit"></p>
      <p class="w3-large"> <a href="#" title="Recupera la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('register','login')">Accedi</a></p>
      <p class="w3-large">Hai dimenticato la password?<a href="#" title="Recupera la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('register','pwdreset')">Recupera la password</a></p>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first one is working perfectly (Login Modal) while in the Register and Reset ones the buttons are not working - they do absolutely nothing.
I am quite new to web development so probably I am missing something basic. Any help would be useful.
Many thanks

I tried adding different IDs to the buttons or different form names but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to close the double form in the register and reset section

```
<form action="forgottenpsw.php" method="post"></form>
<form action="register.php" method="post"></form>
```

you just delete the tag `</form>` in 2 line above, here the update code

Login Modal :

```
<div id="login" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
  <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
      <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
      <i onclick="document.getElementById('login').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
      <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Accedi</h2>
       <label for="email"></label>
    <p><input name= "email" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email" required></p>
    <label for="password"></label>
    <p><input name="password" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="password" placeholder="Inserisci la password" id="password" required></p>
    <p><input  class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Accedi" type="submit"></p>
      <p class="w3-large">Hai dimenticato la password? <a href="#" title="Reimposta la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('login','pwdreset')">Recupera la password</a></p>
       <p class="w3-large">Non sei registrato? <a href="#" title="Registrati" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('login','register')">Registrati</a></p>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Password reset Modal

```
<div id="pwdreset" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
  <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
  <form action="forgottenpsw.php" method="post">
    <i onclick="document.getElementById('pwdreset').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
    
    <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Reimposta la Password</h2>
    <label for="email2"></label>
    <p><input name= "email2" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email2" required></p>
    
    <p><input class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Reimposta" type="submit"></p>
   
    <p class="w3-large"> <a href="#" title="Accedi" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('pwdreset','login')">Accedi a Clear IDD</a></p>
    <p class="w3-large">Non sei registrato? <a href="#" title="Registrati" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('pwdreset','register')">Registrati</a></p>
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Register Modal

```
<div id="register" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom">
  <div class="w3-container w3-white w3-center">
  <form action="register.php" method="post">
    <i onclick="document.getElementById('register').style.display='none'" class="fa fa-remove w3-right w3-button w3-transparent w3-xxlarge cidd-hover-red"></i>
    <h2 class="w3-wide w3-center">Registrati</h2>
    <label for="fname"></label>
    <p><input name= "fname" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" id="fname" required></p>
    <label for="surname"></label>
    <p><input name= "surname" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" id="surname" required></p>
    
    <label for="email3"></label>
    <p><input name= "email3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Inserisci indirizzo e-mail" id="email3" required></p>
    <label for="password3"></label>
    <p><input name="password3" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="password" placeholder="Inserisci la password" id="password3" required></p>
    <label for="password4"></label>
    <p><input name= "password4" class="w3-input w3-border w3-large" type="text" placeholder="Conferma la password" id="password4" required></p>
    <p><input  class="w3-button w3-padding-large cidd-red w3-margin-bottom w3-xlarge" value="Registrati" type="submit"></p>
    <p class="w3-large"> <a href="#" title="Recupera la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('register','login')">Accedi</a></p>
    <p class="w3-large">Hai dimenticato la password?<a href="#" title="Recupera la password" class="w3-hover-opacity" onclick="openModal('register','pwdreset')">Recupera la password</a></p>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use javascript. but the modals are showing fine, the only thing which isn't working is button in the register and reset ones - I don't get why since the code looks the same as the login one.

Comment: this is to open modals: `function openModal(closeMod, openMod){
 document.getElementById(closeMod).style.display='none';
 document.getElementById(openMod).style.display = "block";
}`

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't notice; my code editor adds tag closing when not needed...

Comment: your welcome.. i just edit the reply the tag</form> yesterday is showing in reply